# How to have two different comment sections on the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have a single-product.php page on my wordpress site.

I currently have one comment section where users can leave reviews on the product by filling in star ratings, and filling out a title and description of their review.

They cant submit unless all the fields (including the stars) are filled out.

```
$comments_args = array(

        'label_submit' => __( 'Send', 'textdomain' ),

        'title_reply' => __( 'Leave a Review', 'textdomain' ),
        fields".
        'comment_notes_after' => '',

        'comment_field' => '
        <p class="comment-form-comment">
        <label for="comment">'
         . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . 
         '</label>
         <br />
         <textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true">
         </textarea>
         </p>',
);

$loggedIn = is_user_logged_in();
if($loggedIn){
        ?>
        <div class = 'leave-review' id = 'leaveReview'>
                <?php 
                    comment_form( $comments_args );
                 ?>
        </div>
        <?php
}
```

I want to add a "community" section right underneath the reviews sections where users can leave questions and respond to each other. The problem is these comments have to be separate from the review comments because im using those to calculate an average of the product based on the average of the stars the user leaves and this new section will have different fields for the user to fill out.

Comment: I also have a function that is hooked to comment submit, whenever a comment is submitted it runs this function. One way of doing this i'm thinking is to add a meta value to the comment when it is submitted that would differentiate the two different types of comments.

Comment: How about using the regular Comments system that's included with WordPress for this?